# Capybara: Test generated script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, capybara

I am using ajax to update follow/unfollow users in my page. If user is not signed in and he clicks on follow page then he should be redirect to sign in page:

```
def identify_user
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
    render js: "window.location = '/'" if @user.nil? || !user_signed_in?
  end
```

since follow button has `remote: true` set, I can't use simple `redirect_to`. How do I test this using capybara?

```
scenario "Follow when user is not logged in", js: true do
    sign_up_with("t@test.com","test1","secret12345")
    click_link "logout"
    visit "/test1" #takes to user 'test1' page
    click_link "Follow test1" #link to follow user
    expect(current_path).to eql('/')
  end
```

Above code doesn't work, it just opens my default browser.. well with 
`window.location = '/'`
Changes in method to handle redirecting of user so that test is easier to write are also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an rspec expectation on an element on the page instead of the current_path?  That would prove to be a more robust test over simply verifying the URL.  Something like:

```
expect(page).to have_css('input#password')
```